# Deleting item in one way linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I need a function that searches an item from linked list based on its position saves the info in a variable and deletes it. For example I want to delete fifth item in the list and save its contents to int& number; and string& text; 
My List is linked only in one direction.
I think I have managed to do the finding but removing it is a bit harder.

```
private:
    struct List_cell{
        unsigned number;
        string text;
        List_cell *next;
    };
    List_cell *list_first_;
```

.

```
bool LinkedList::find_and_remove(unsigned& position, unsigned& count, unsigned& found_number, string& found_text){
List_cell *current = list_first_;

if(current == nullptr){
    return false;
}
else{
    while(current != nullptr){
        count++;
        current = current->next;
        if(count == position){
            found_number = current->number;
            found_text = current->text;
                            //here should be the deleting i think
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Have I done everything correctly and any suggestions how to do the deleting?

Comment: Well, you should remember the object linking to the one you want to remove. With the code you have you loose the link you want to change right before your check...

Comment: I suggest you write out the steps needed on paper first, the (re)code the solution. After coded, step though the code line by line in a debugger to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming lemma: all problems can be solved by additional layers of indirection:

```
bool LinkedList::find_and_remove( unsigned& position,
                                  unsigned& count,
                                  unsigned& found_number,
                                  string& found_text )
{
    List_cell **work = &list_first_;
    while(*work != nullptr) {
        if ( ++count == position ) {
            List_cell *tmp = *work;
            *work = (*work)->next;
            found_number = tmp->number;
            found_test = tmp->text;
            delete tmp;
            return true;
        }
        work = &(*work)->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh.. I dont think it works. when i use this it seems to alwys delete the first! Is this really working or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Whoops...sorry.  Forgot a line.  It's what happens when I write code without testing it :)

Comment: BTW: if you use that in a homework assignment your professor will almost certainly not believe you wrote it :)

Comment: Why did you declare `work` as `List_cell **`?  Now `work` must be deference every time it is called.  I can't see any low level benefit either because it's reassigning an address vs reassigning an address.  Or does the size of what the pointer is pointing to determine the size of the pointer?

Comment: Ah I get it now `*work` is equivalent to `previous->next` so `*work = (*work)->next` is what unlinks the found node.  However `work = &(*work)->next` needs to be inside `else`. Otherwise if the found node is at the end of the list, then `**work = null`, and `(*work)->next` or `(**work).next` is undefined.

Comment: The main benefit here is that there's no special code for handling deleting the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You've found the node to delete, so now all you need is linking the node *before* it to the node *after* it. So, you'll need a pointer to the node before that one.

You need to modify your code as

```
if head is null, return false
initialize counter to 0
create two pointers: p as head and q as head->next
while q != null do
    if counter == position do <- q is pointing to the node you need to remove
        store the info from q
        p->next = q->next <- this is where the node gets removed
        return true
    q = q->next
    p = p->next
return false
```

Or do it recursively: (not always suggested, but requires less code)

```
deleteNode(head, position):
    if head == null 
        return null
    if position == 0:
        return head->next
    head->next = deleteNode(head->next, position - 1)
    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the `next` pointer of the node before the deleted node and attach that to the node after the deleted cell.

So you will need a previous pointer

```
List_cell* previous;
```

And in your while loop

```
count++;
previous = current;
current = current->next;
if(count == position){
    found_number = current->number;
    found_text = current->text;
    previous->next = current->next;
    delete current;
    return true;
}
```